# Maven Project Error with build path src/main/resources

Tags: eclipse, maven, buildpath

I have a maven project that have four build path

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

but when I perform, in eclipse, "Maven->Update Project Configuration",the build path "src/main/resources" is removed and stay as simple folders.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of m2e are you using?

I currently am using m2e 1.2, the latest N release.

For your maven configuration, just note:

- Don't specify your build paths: m2e & Maven will recognise those are part of the build paths.  This is defined in Maven's internal [super-pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html%20super-pom)
- src/main/resources is *on* the build path, but is not a source directory.  Meaning, Eclipse may not show it as being on Java's source path within your project, but any files added there are included in the built package / on execution.  Therefore, being just 'simple' folders is correct.

Comment: Strange, older versions of m2e I am using, DO put src/main/resources as source directory.  Does such behavior changed or what?

Comment: I believe it has yes.  I remember when it used to, but to be honest, it's not necessary and just adds clutter.  Didn't like it at first, but it's nice now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `src/main/resources` folder to be mapped as a source folder in eclipse, just add the following line in the `.classpath` file of your project:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
```